# How to catch Windows shell script errors launched from VBA code?

Tags: vba, error-handling, batch-file

I'm launching a batch script from VBA with the `Shell` function:

```
myRes = Shell("myScript.cmd")
```

Is there a way to know if it runs successfully or if there were execution errors?

Comment: When you manually run `myScript.cmd` from the command line, how do you know whether it executed successfully or not? Does the script return an error code? What's the success criterion?

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you try the [WshShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99) object instead of the native Shell function.

```
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1 'or whatever suits you best
Dim errorCode As Integer

errorCode = wsh.Run("myScript.cmd", windowStyle, waitOnReturn)

If errorCode = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Execution successful. No error to report."
Else
    MsgBox "Program exited with error code " & errorCode & "."
End If
```

Though note that:

> If `bWaitOnReturn` is set to false (the default), the Run method returns immediately after starting the program, automatically returning 0 (not to be interpreted as an error code).

So to detect whether the program executed successfully, you need `waitOnReturn` to be set to True as in my example above. Otherwise it will just return zero no matter what.

[This earlier answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902022/wait-for-shell-to-finish-then-format-cells/8906912#8906912) may be helpful as well.

Comment: The value of erroCode is always 0

Comment: @Mehdi Did you read the [documentation on `Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky)? It states "If [`bWaitOnReturn` is] set to `false` (the default), the `Run` method returns immediately after starting the program, automatically returning 0 (not to be interpreted as an error code)." Maybe you didn't set `waitOnReturn` to `True`?

Answer (score 3):

You can catch the error level if you are that the command will return 0 on success:
http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18663

> ## Get the exit code of a process
>
> In a few cases, in particular when
>   running MsDos batch files from within a VB application, you may want
>   to determine the `ERRORLEVEL` set by an external application. You can't
>   do it with a plain Shell statement, but the job becomes easy with the
>   support of the `GetProcessExitCode` API function:
>
> ```
> Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
> Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As _
>     Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long
> Private Declare Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As _
>     Long, lpExitCode As Long) As Long
> Const STILL_ACTIVE = &H103
> Const PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = &H400
>
>
> Private Sub cmdRunNotepad_Click()
>     Dim hTask As Long
>     Dim hProcess As Long
>     Dim exitCode As Long
>
>     hTask = Shell("Notepad", vbNormalFocus)
>     hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, False, hTask)
>
>     ' loop until the process returns a valid exit code
>     Do
>         ' relinquish this CPU time slice
>         Sleep 100
>         DoEvents
>         ' query for exit code
>         GetExitCodeProcess hProcess, exitCode
>     Loop While exitCode = STILL_ACTIVE
>
>     MsgBox "Exit code = " & exitCode, vbInformation
>
>
> End Sub
> ```
>
> Francesco Balena

or you can try something like this:

```
myRes = Shell("cmd /c myScript.cmd&&echo success")
```

here's  more info about conditional execution: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php

But in both cases you rely on exit codes.