# Get Logs and Exitcode from Knime. Call with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, knime

I've These Command in my vba code:

```
Call Shell("""C:\Program Files\KNIME\knime.exe"" -consoleLog -nosave -nosplash -reset --launcher.suppressErrors -application org.knime.product.KNIME_BATCH_APPLICATION -workflowDir=""C:\Users\test\knime-workspace\Testing\testshell"" -workflow.variable=OUTFILETEST,""C:\Users\test\Desktop\test.xlsx"",String")
```

Everything is Fine. But the knime batch mode has exit code. These codes tell me how successful the workflow is.

How can i catch the exitcode in vba ?

And second question. How can i log the errors etc from the knimebatch?

windows vba

Comment: What do you get if you use `ReturnCode = Shell(...)`?

Comment: @nekomatic in this case i get 2432 :)
but The exitcode is just 1,2,3 or 4.

Comment: i used wsshell from this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948771/how-to-catch-windows-shell-script-errors-launched-from-vba-code