# Check result of pscp transfer in VBA

Tags: vba, scp, pscp

I use `pscp` to copy a file from Windows to Unix and I run it using VBA.
After `pscp` command how will I ensure that file is transferred successfully?

```vb
shell "pscp -P 22 -pw abcd test.csv user@XXX.com:/u01/test"
```

Answer (score 0):

Test `pscp` exit code.  `0` is success, `1` is error.

For examples of code that test exit code of an application, see:

- [How to catch Windows shell script errors launched from VBA code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11948771/850848)
- [VBA Shell and Wait with Exit Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1439200/850848)