# Can you determine if FFmpeg executed correctly based on the return?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ffmpeg

I have written a script to mass-tag a large audio library. The tag info is stored in an Access database. I wrote a vba sub that invokes an FFmpeg command line.

`newCmdStr = ffmpeg -i myFile.mp3 tag-info output.mp3`

`Shell ("cmd.exe /k " & newCmdStr)`

Is there a way to determine if it runs correctly?
I tried printing the return
`MsgBox(Shell(newCmdStr))`,
but it seems to return a random number, I can't tell what indicates if the command worked.

The most likely error would be a file not found error, but there could be some other things.
If it ran, I would log the filepath of the new file, if it failed I would note that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on Super User or Video Production."

Comment: @braX That's an exceptionally poor close reason for a question asking to programmatically get a return value when running ffmpeg using VBA

Comment: You may try the solution described in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948771/how-to-catch-windows-shell-script-errors-launched-from-vba-code). According to the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199216/how-to-tell-if-ffmpeg-errored-or-not) FFmpeg returns non-zero status in case of an error. (But according the the comment it's not always working).

Answer (score 3):

`Shell` invokes a command asynchronously, and can never get a return value. It returns the Process ID.

Furthermore, it would return the program ID of the program you're trying to run, which, in this case, is `cmd.exe` since that's first in your string.

Use `WScript.Shell` instead, which has `.Run` which can invoke commands synchronously, or `.Exec` which invokes asynchronously but allows getting return values.

```
Dim WshShell, oExec
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("ffmpeg -i myFile.mp3 tag-info output.mp3")

Do While oExec.Status = 0
     DoEvents
     'You probably want to sleep here to prevent high CPU usage
     'See https://stackoverflow.com/a/469358/7296893
Loop

Debug.Print oExec.ExitCode
```

Comment: I tried following this, but the program never exits the oExec.Status loop. A cmd window pops up with the label C:\Program Files\ffmpeg-4.4-full_build\bin\ffmpeg.exe, but it doesn't display any text, and does not seem to be running anything.