# using excel vba to open specific version of brio (hyperion reporting studio)

Tags: vba, excel, hyperion, brio

I was using Hyperion version 9.3.3 to process my queries and was recently upgraded to version 11.  The problem I'm encountering is that version 11 doesn't have the same amount to computational space as 9.3.3, so until I create a solution to this I'd like to continue to use 9.3.3 (which is still on my machine along with version 11).  Does anyone know how I would do this in macros created in Excel vba?  My current code is quite simple:

```
Set mybrio = CreateObject("BrioQuery.Application")
mybrio.Documents.Open (excel_loc & "\" & brio_filename)
```

This code opens version 11 though by default and I want version 9.3.3.  Can anyone help me alter this code to have specifically target 9.3.3?

Answer (score 0):

In VBA IDE window- Tool-->Reference --There will be the list of Visual Basic Applications. Check if there are two versions available in it? if so Uncheck the latest version and check the old version

Comment: Neither version is in that list.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073152/how-to-open-specific-version-of-word-2007-2010-in-excel

Comment: Please use the above link as a  reference for your requirement

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I've tried a similar approach as was used for 'Word' in the link.  If I use: Set mybrio = CreateObject("BrioQuery.Application.6"), I can open the new version 11 app. but there is no number associated with the older version 9.9.3 version.

Comment: @SlowJoeCrow I remember when we were testing if things would break going to version 11, there was one we used.  I can't remember what it was.  I want to say it was some variant like `Brio.Application`  Unfortunately, I don't work there anymore and can't look at my old code.  Google isn't helping me remember.  Maybe I'm misremembering.