# wait until command completes in vba before another starts

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below portion of code in an `excel 2010 vba`.  My question is how do I run the `java process` and wait until it completes before `perl` process is called?

```
' CALL JAVA PROGRAM USING SHELL '
Dim wshell As Object

Set wshell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
wshell.Run Chr(34) & "C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\EmArray\Design\java.bat"

' UPDATE PERL VARIABLES '
Dim PerlCommand As String, PerlParameters As String
Dim var As String, var1 As String, var2 As String, var3 As String

var = MyDirectory
var1 = var & "sample_descriptor.txt"
var2 = "C:\cygwin\home\cmccabe\test_probes.txt"
var3 = var & "output.txt"

' CALL PERL '
PerlCommand = """C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\EmArray\Design\perl.bat"""
PerlParameters = """" & var & """" & " " & _
"""" & var1 & """" & " " & _
"""" & var2 & """" & " " & _
"""" & var3 & """"
CreateObject("wscript.shell").Run PerlCommand & "  " & PerlParameters
```

edit: I just saw that post know and it solved my issue... thank you and I apologize, I had a variable named incorrectly :).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait for Shell to finish, then format cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902022/wait-for-shell-to-finish-then-format-cells)

Comment: This was not a duplicate but that post I just saw and that solved it.  Thank you :).