# Excel VBA: Functions not running synchronously

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a macro on button click. On this button click, I have three functions to run one after another.

Code is:

```
Sub submit()
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Call RUnCode
    Call copy_paste_sheet
    Call cumulative_percent
End Sub
```

Code for RUnCode is:

```
Private Sub RUnCode()
    Dim pyPrgm As String, pyScript As String
    pyPrgm = "python "
    pyScript = "C:\Users\Kishan\Desktop\script.py"
    Call Shell(pyPrgm & pyScript, vbMinimizedNoFocus)
End Sub
```

Function RUnCode is running a python script through command line. It is takes some time to run, and I need data from python script for copy_paste_sheet and cumulative_percent function (Both functions are simple excel sheet manipulations).

But problem is: before the RUnCode is over, other two functions are running, thereby leading to processing the wrong data.

Can you help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into wait commands in VBA.  I believe there is a way you can make the code wait until the script has completed before running the next portion

Comment: Can you post the code in the `RUnCode` sub-routine?

Comment: Also check out using `WshShell` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902022/wait-for-shell-to-finish-then-format-cells

Comment: @Robin I have inserted the code for RUnCode function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
Private Sub RunCode()

    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim strCmd As String
    Dim lngErrorCode As Long

    strCmd = "python C:\Users\Kishan\Desktop\script.py"
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    lngErrorCode = objShell.Run(strCmd, 1, True)
    Debug.Print lngErrorCode

End Sub
```