# Can I ask VBA to sleep for a while before continuing to the next line of code?

Tags: python, vba, excel

I worte a VBA snippet that calls a macro in another workbook written by my collegue. That macro actually calls python to do something else and create a new workbook. After that I need to open that new workbook and do some other things. However, the python code takes some time to run and if I simply use

```
Application.Run "'CollegueWorkbook.xlsm'!pythonmacro"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("NewWorkbook.xlsx")
```

I will get `Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range` beacause by the time `Set wb = Workbooks.Open("NewWorkbook.xlsx")` is executed, the python code has not created a new workbook yet I guess (it looks like VBA code won't wait for python thread)

I wonder how I can let VBA to sleep and continue to next line of code only when the new workbook is produced. Or if there is any other workarounds?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902022/wait-for-shell-to-finish-then-format-cells-synchronously-execute-a-command

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to pause a script.

1) `Application.Wait` This is for continuing at a set time.

2) `Sleep` This one is for pausing for a set duration.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `Application.Wait`
This waits until a specific time, so if you want to wait for 10 seconds, use 
`Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:10")`
You could think about a loop so you don't have to wait longer then neccessary:

```
Dim retry As Long
Set wb = Nothing
For retry = 1 To 10
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:10")
    If Dir("NewWorkbook.xlsx") <> "" Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open("NewWorkbook.xlsx")
        Exit For
    End If
Next retry
If wb Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Didn't work..."
Else
    ...
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be this. (not tested)

```
On Error Resume Next
Application.Run "'CollegueWorkbook.xlsm'!pythonmacro"
Do While wb Is Nothing
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("NewWorkbook.xlsx")
Loop
```