# When I run Python script from VBA it doesn't work but when I run it from Spyder it does work, how do I fix this?

Tags: python, excel, vba

So I have two workbooks: One workbook is called "merged.xlsx" and this has data that is the result of a Python script.

The other workbook is Action_Log.xlsm and I run the macro in order to get the data from merged.xlsx into Action_Log.xlsm.

The very first thing my macro needs to do is run the Python script in order to update the merged.xlsx file:

```
'run python script to update merged workbook
ret_value = Shell("C:\Python34\python-3.4.4.amd64\python.exe " & "G:\Data\Shared\Action Logs\ActionLogAppend4py.py", vbNormalFocus)
```

However, when I run the macro my merged file doesn't update (which of course means that the Python script didn't run even though it seems like it did because the rest of the macro continues and runs and hence no error on this line). When I run the Python script from Spyder my merged file updates just fine. So I don't know what the issue could be?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Path which could contain spaces should be quoted:

```
ret_value = Shell("C:\Python34\python-3.4.4.amd64\python.exe " & _
       """G:\Data\Shared\Action Logs\ActionLogAppend4py.py""", vbNormalFocus)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked just fine. However, is there a way in which I can get the Python script to finish running (and hence the merged file updated) before the macro continues to run?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902022/wait-for-shell-to-finish-then-format-cells-synchronously-execute-a-command