# Print File - Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a macro that I can use to print PDF files. The PDF files will be saved in a folder to print. The path will be given that folder path where I save all PDF files. My questions are:

1) Once the files are saved in folder, is it possible to sort it automatically like first come first print. Now the issue is -  prints did not come out in order of how the files are – we have to reconcile all files, so looking for each one in a random list order would take lots of time.

2) Is it possible to have the files automatically deleted from the folder after the printing is completed?

```
Public Sub Print_All_PDF_Files_in_Folder()

Dim folder As String
Dim PDFfilename As String

folder = "\\maple.fg.rbc.com\data\toronto\user_3\315606053\myWorkspace\Desktop\test"    'CHANGE AS REQUIRED
If Right(folder, 1) <> "\" Then folder = folder & "\"

PDFfilename = Dir(folder & "*.pdf", vbNormal)
While Len(PDFfilename) <> 0
    If Not PDFfilename Like "*ecg*" Then
        Print_PDF folder & PDFfilename
    End If
    PDFfilename = Dir()  ' Get next matching file
  Wend
End Sub

Sub Print_PDF(sPDFfile As String)
  Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe /p /h " & Chr(34) & sPDFfile & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus
' This is path of Adobe in the desktop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no build in way to sort files. However, it is rather easy to read the filenames and -dates into arrays and sort them manually, but you have to use the `FilesystemObject` rather than using `dir` to get the file dates.

You can find an example to do so for example here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5f27936e-1d98-44df-8f69-0f81624c4b92/read-files-in-a-folder-in-descending-order-with-file-name-or-date-created?forum=accessdev

The command to delete a file with VBA is `kill`, or you can use the `.DeleteFile` method of `FilesystemObject`. However, this will work only if the printing is already done, so you have to wait for your shell-command to finish. For this, you have to use the `wscript.shell`, see for example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8906912/7599798