# vba: execute shell after finishing previous shell

Tags: vba

How to call the second shell in this case after pressing pause?

```
Shell "cmd /c cd %tmp% && echo hello > tmpfile && pause", 1
Shell "cmd /c cd %tmp% && echo hello > tmpfile && pause", 1
```

and in this case

```
Shell "cmd /c cd %tmp% && echo hello > tmpfile", 0
Shell "cmd /c cd %tmp% && echo hello > tmpfile", 0
```

Comment: `Shell` is asynchronous - it just returns immediately. I'm not exactly clear on what you are trying to do - a more detailed explanation of the purpose of the code would be helpful in answering this.

Comment: I want to execute the code from `cmd.exe /c` and the same after it.

Comment: That's apparent from the code above. Are you just looking for a way to make a blocking call to `Shell`?

Comment: I want the commands to be executed after finishing the previous ones. `cmd.exe /c mycommands` >  `cmd.exe /c mycommands` > `cmd.exe /c mycommands`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait for Shell to finish, then format cells - synchronously execute a command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902022/wait-for-shell-to-finish-then-format-cells-synchronously-execute-a-command)

Comment: Can you give an example? I'm not good at programming in VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Shell` command you're using is **[asynchronous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony_(computer_programming))** meaning it can run more than one process at a time, so in the case of your two `Shell` statements in a row, both will be executed simultaneously.

An alternative way is to instead use the `Run` command of Windows Script Host (`WScript.Shell`) since it has more options including one to wait for execution of the program to finish before it continues.

```
Sub ShellWait(fName As String, Optional showWindow As Boolean = True)
    Dim wsh As Object
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    wsh.Run fName, -showWindow, True
End Sub
```

You can also hide the window completely by specifying `False` as the second parameter. (Caution with that option if user input is required!)

---

**For example:**

```
Sub demo()
    ShellWait "x:\test.bat"
    Beep
    MsgBox "Finished running!"
End Sub
```

---

### More Information:

- Chip Pearson : [**Shell and Wait**](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ShellAndWait.aspx)
- Stack Overflow : [**Wait for shell command to complete**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15951837/8112776)
- Stack Overflow : [**Wait for Shell to finish, then format cells**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8906912/8112776)
- DevGuru : [**WSH » wshshell » Run**](http://www.devguru.com/content/technologies/wsh/wshshell-run.html)

Comment: Do I have to put in a .bat file? I would like to avoid it.